# Python multiprocessing: how to create x number of processes and get return value back

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I have a program that I created using threads, but then I learned that threads don't run concurrently in python and processes do. As a result, I am trying to rewrite the program using multiprocessing, but I am having a hard time doing so. I have tried following several examples that show how to create the processes and pools, but I don't think it's exactly what I want.

Below is my code with the attempts I have tried. The program tries to estimate the value of pi by randomly placing points on a graph that contains a circle. The program takes two command-line arguments: one is the number of threads/processes I want to create, and the other is the total number of points to try placing on the graph (N).

```
import math
import sys
from time import time
import concurrent.futures
import random
import multiprocessing as mp


def myThread(arg):
    # Take care of imput argument
    n = int(arg)
    print("Thread received. n = ", n)

    # main calculation loop
    count = 0
    for i in range (0, n):
        x = random.uniform(0,1)
        y = random.uniform(0,1)
        d = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
        if (d < 1):
            count = count + 1
    print("Thread found ", count, " points inside circle.")
    return count;
        
# end myThread

# receive command line arguments
if (len(sys.argv) == 3):
    N = sys.argv[1]  # original ex: 0.01
    N = int(N)
    totalThreads = sys.argv[2]
    totalThreads = int(totalThreads)
    print("N = ", N)
    print("totalThreads = ", totalThreads)
else:
    print("Incorrect number of arguments!")
    sys.exit(1)

if ((totalThreads == 1) or (totalThreads == 2) or (totalThreads == 4) or (totalThreads == 8)):
    print()
else:
    print("Invalid number of threads. Please use 1, 2, 4, or 8 threads.")
    sys.exit(1)

# start experiment
t = int(time() * 1000)  # begin run time
total = 0

# ATTEMPT 1
# processes = []
# for i in range(totalThreads):
#     process = mp.Process(target=myThread, args=(N/totalThreads))
#     processes.append(process)
#     process.start()
    
# for process in processes:
#     process.join()

# ATTEMPT 2
#pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
#total = pool.map(myThread, [N/totalThreads])

# ATTEMPT 3
#for i in range(totalThreads):
    #total = total + pool.map(myThread, [N/totalThreads])
#    p = mp.Process(target=myThread, args=(N/totalThreads))
#    p.start()

# ATTEMPT 4
# with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
#     for i in range(totalThreads):
#         future = executor.submit(myThread, N/totalThreads) # start thread
#         total = total + future.result() # get result

# analyze results
pi = 4 * total / N
print("pi estimate =", pi)
delta_time = int(time() * 1000) - t # calculate time required
print("Time =", delta_time, " milliseconds")
```

I thought that creating a loop from 0 to totalThreads that creates a process for each iteration would work. I also wanted to pass in N/totalThreads (to divide the work), but it seems that processes take in an iterable list rather than an argument to pass to the method.

What is it I am missing with multiprocessing? Is it at all possible to even do what I want to do with processes?
Thank you in advance for any help, it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The short answer is that you can do what you want with Processes. But it's unclear what your objective is. Your function myThread looks like it will execute very quickly (unless the argument passed is massive). When compared to traditional multithreading, there's a greater (and potentially significant in your case) overhead in constructing and starting the Process. So, if it's performance you're after, I'd stick with threads

Comment: @DarkKnight This is a practice program for something I am gonna do that involves heavier calculations. Mainly doing this so I can get familiar with how threading/processing in python works before moving to my bigger program

Comment: You should pass arguments as tuple, so instead of `args=(N/totalThreads)` you want to do `args=(N/totalThreads,)`. Processes are usually more costly to create than threads, and the overhead might be too big in certain cases.  If you really want to do this fast, you should consider using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). Literally their front page has this Monte Carlo simulation as example.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your code and used some hard-coded values which may or may not be reasonable.

```
import math
import concurrent.futures
import random
from datetime import datetime


def myThread(arg):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, arg[0]):
        x = random.uniform(0, 1)
        y = random.uniform(0, 1)
        d = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
        if (d < 1):
            count += 1
    return count


N = 10_000
T = 8

_start = datetime.now()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(myThread, (int(N / T),)): _ for _ in range(T)}
    total = 0
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        total += future.result()
_end = datetime.now()
print(f'Estimate for PI = {4 * total / N}')
print(f'Run duration = {_end-_start}')
```

A typical output on my machine looks like this:-

Estimate for PI = 3.1472
Run duration = 0:00:00.008895

Bear in mind that the number of threads you start is effectively managed by the ThreadPoolExecutor (TPE) [ when constructed with no parameters ]. It makes decisions about the number of threads that can run based on your machine's processing capacity (number of cores etc). Therefore you could, if you really wanted to, set T to a very high number and the TPE will block execution of any new threads until it determines that there is capacity.

Comment: Saving the futures as a keys in a dictionary with the values being the corresponding arguments to `submit`  is useful if you need to recover the arguments whenever you are processing the results in completion rather than submission order as you are doing here. **But** you are *not* recovering the arguments here, so it makes more sense just to save the futures in a list. Also, why is the argument to `submit` a tuple with a single `int` element rather than just a single `int` element? And if this is a constant, why even pass it at all?

Comment: By the way, without using multithreading or multiprocessing, i.e. `
    total = 0;
    for _ in range(T):;
        total += myThread(int(N / T))
` runs faster. That is to say, this is not a good candidate for either multithreading or multiprocessing.

Comment: @Booboo I completely agree that multi-threading/processing is overkill in this case. However, OP did say that his example is a "practice" program for something more substantial which, I guess, may be suited to MP or MT. My code shows how it could be done not - necessarily how it should be done

Comment: My last comment was more for the OP's benefit than for yours and both comments are just some observations; I did upvote your answer.